# Can I use a component that uses VueX without my app also using VueX?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, arcgis-js-api

I would like to use this component in my Vue app: https://commbocc.github.io/hcflgov-vue-esri-search/docs/

However it is throwing an error: `TypeError: "t.$store is undefined"`

I suspect the cause is that I am not using VueX, so I'm failing to initialise a VueX store that the component is looking for.

In general, is it possible to use a component that uses VueX if my app does not? Is there some way around this? I think the effort involved in incorporating VueX would be too high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. In most cases, people create [vue-plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html). When doing that, you can install them like `npm install myCoolPlugin` and use them in your app by importing it: `import myCoolPlugin from 'myCoolPlugin'` and then depending of the plugin, you can either globally install it like vuex does:

`Vue.use(myCoolPlugin)`

or you can explicitly use the plugin's components as you wish directly where you are going to use them like so:

```
import {coolButton, coolInput} from 'myCoolPlugin';
export default {
    name: 'home-page',
    components: [coolButton, coolInput],
    ...
}
```

Plugins also have a package.json file that holds metadata about what that plugin depends on etc (just like your app). When you `npm i myCoolPlugin`, npm checks the plugin's package.json file to see what 3rd party packages the plugin depends on and then continues to install them in **your app's node_modules.**

The issue with your component "esri-search" is that it is not set up as a package/plugin. Therefore it will not install any dependencies it needs ([like vuex, lodash etc...](https://github.com/Commbocc/hcflgov-vue-esri-search/blob/master/package.json#L14)) in your app.

This is why you had to install vuex as a dependency to your app, because when you copy paste this component in to your app, it is not a plugin, it *becomes your app.*

Does this make sense? :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems in this case I was able to solve that error like this:

`npm install --save vuex`

In `main.js`:

```
import VueX from 'vuex';
Vue.use(VueX);
```

This doesn't fully answer whether or not this would always be the case though, so open to better answers.